# Excel Weird Decimal Point Calculation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

We have some weird calculation scenario in Microsoft excel, this simple addition operation resulting 1 at 13 decimal digit whereby it should be zero

[image]

But when i extract the value in formula the result is correct (both formula value is the same but the result is different)

[image]

From human understanding addition calculation will reduce the decimal digit rather than add it.
Is this by design or bugs ?

Comment: Possibly one the original numbers has a 1 at that decimal location but the display does not show it because of limiting the display. Increase the decimal display for the other 2 numbers to 30 decimals to find out.

Comment: In Excel, it's not the same what you see than what the real value is. Is there any format applied to cell? Is it general?

Comment: How are the values in the first column being computed?  If you just type them in as you show them, your problem is not reproducible.  See [Understanding Floating Point Precision](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/#:~:text=Excel%20store%2015%20significant%20digits,be%20stored%20in%20binary%20format.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly guess that this is a gap from the limited precision of floating point numbers. Accuracy of digital numbers is limited. Numbers in excel are saved in binary format(but displayed in decimal format). This means that the "0" is not as protected as in the decimal system. Usually Excel tries to cover this up for examples like yours.

Also, if your numbers derive from complex calculations (e.g. square-roots), the accuracy can be limited as most functions use approximation with limited iterations to give a result.

You can find more information about floating point arithmetic here. The blog is about pythin but the way it works is similar.
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, seems your analysis is correct, actually my program (dotnet core base) has the same issue with this, how do we mitigate this, do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: What is the purpose of your data? Science? Finance?

Comment: You can either hide it by changing the format to a format with less decimals or use the round(number, number of decimals) function

Comment: finance (banking), i did what you suggest  and microsoft excel do(hiding the decimal format and autoround) but actually they demand all money dividing operation should have end result 0 and can revert back to the value before it's divided. say you have asset 1000 with 3 month depreciation, so 1000/3, first 333.33, second 333.33, last 333.34 so it's 1000 in total...is there any standard way to do this kind of dividing calculation perhaps in excel ?  (Sorry OOT)